# Visual Studio 2015 failed to create and edit c++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a trouble with C++ projects in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

First of all I cannot create new c++ project (simple console application). When I click on "OK" button in "New Project" wizard the window hide and show up again. (Nothing happened)

[image: Window 1]

Second problem. When I open existing project and try to edit C++ setting I only see "Configuration Properties".

[image: Window 2]

I've already tried "Repair" in VS2015 intaller and it doesn't help. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Since repairing didn't help, try to completely uninstall and reinstall. Yes it will take some hours, maybe.

Comment: Maybe try to create a new project in a directory with a full ASCII path. VS2015 itself doesn't mind arbitrary Unicode pathnames, but maybe some addin/plugin has a problem with those.

Comment: Tends to be caused by having a VS edition installed previously and not perfectly uninstalled.  That leaves garbage in the registry that prevents sub-components from being installed because the installer thinks they are already present.  Run the installer with the /uninstall /force options to get a more thorough clean-up.

Comment: Reinstall VS with "/uninstall /force" solve my problems. Thanks to all for comments.

Answer (score 4):

According the official site, this is a ugly and strange bug of some VS updates:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3

In some cases, applying Updates to VS 2015 can cause the optional feature selections for Visual C++ (e.g. Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015) to become deselected and uninstalled. This issue can be resolved by re-selecting the required Visual C++ features in the Visual Studio 2015 setup dialog.

1. In "Programs and Features" (Add/Remove Programs), select "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015", then click "Change".
2. In the Visual Studio setup dialog, click "Modify"
3. Select/check "Programming Languages->Visual C++->Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015" and other features under "Programming Languages->Visual C++", as appropriate.
4. Click "UPDATE".